# How do i get rid of this black bar?

Tags: html, css, web

http://myma.in/

How can i get rid of this black bar on the bottom of my page? its driving me insane! Any ideas on what i could do? It would be of a great assistance!

Code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>myma.in</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker|Oswald:300|Ubuntu+Condensed|Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/heimer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100%; }
      body { min-height: 100%; }
      body {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18pt;
        
        margin: 0.5em 1.5em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        
        text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em black, 0 0 0.8em black, 0 0 1em black, 0 0 2em black;
      }
      p {
        margin: 0.4em 0.3em;
      }
      .center {
        display: block; text-align: center;
      }
      .small {
        font-size: 0.8em;
      }
      img {
        margin: 1.0em;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1em black, 0 0 2.5em black;
      }
      img.bigger {
        width: 60%;
      }
      div#content {
        margin: 0.5em;
        padding: 1.5em 0.4em;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        width: 25em;
      }
      div#copy {
        margin: 1.5em 0.5em;
      }
      h1,h2,h3 {
        margin: 0.1em 0.25em;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      div#link {
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      a#action {
        font-size: 26pt;
      }
      a#action:hover {
        color: #eee;
      }
      div#link input {
        margin: 0; padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
        max-width: 6em;
        
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 36pt;
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        
        border: none;
        outline-width: 0;
        
        background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
      }
      
      ul#regionselect {
        display: inline-table;
        margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 0.2em;
        list-style-type: none;
      }
      ul#regionselect li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
        
        color: #222;
        background: linear-gradient( to bottom,
          #aaa, #888
        );
        outline: solid #777 1px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14pt;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em rgba(100,100,100,0.6);
        
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      ul#regionselect li.selected {
        background: linear-gradient( to bottom,
          #ddd, #bbb
        );
      }
      ul#regionselect li:hover {
        background: linear-gradient( to bottom,
          #ddd, #ffb
        );
      }
      
      
      h1 { font-size: 96pt; font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif; }
      h2 { font-size: 28pt; position: relative; top: -0.3em; }
      h3 { font-size: 24pt; font-weight: normal; }
      a { text-align: center; }
      a,a:visited { color: white; }
      #wrapper { padding: 0.5em; }
      #disclaimer { position: absolute; top: 1em; right: 1em; }
      
    </style>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" async></script>
    <!-- script(src='/champion.js')-->
    <script src="/ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/client.js"></script>
    <script src="/jquery.tubular.1.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="content">
        <h1>myma.in</h1>
        <h2>OH GOD IM MID WHO DO I PLAY?!</h2><img src="/garenajax2.gif" title="for the love of god please no" class="bigger">
        <div id="link"><a id="action" href="http://myma.in/na/RiotPhreak">http://myma.in/na/RiotPhreak</a></div>
        <script src="/landinglink.js" async></script>
        <h3>Enter your summoner name, choose your server, then press enter to get started!</h3>
        <p class="center">or read <a href="http://myma.in/help.md">our help and our plan for the future</a><span>.</span></p>
        <div id="copy">
          <p>Sometimes your main gets first-picked or banned...</p>
          <p>...you're last pick and stuck with the one role you can't play...</p>
          <p>...you're bored and want to try a champ you bought ages ago.</p>
          <p>
            Don't despair!
            Be prepared to rise up to the challenge!
            Draft a roster of your best champs and never be lost for a pick again!
            
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="disclaimer">
        myma.in isn't endorsed by Riot Games and doesn't reflect the views
        or opinions of Riot Games or anyone officially involved in producing
        or managing League of Legends.
        League of Legends and Riot Games are trademarks or registered
        trademarks of Riot Games, Inc. League of Legends © Riot Games, Inc.
      </div>
      <style type="text/css">
        #disclaimer {
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 11pt;
          opacity: 0.9;
          max-width: 40em;
          /*margin: 2em auto;*/
        }
        
      </style>
    </div>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
      
      ga('create', 'UA-54111819-1', { 'sampleRate' : 100, 'siteSpeedSampleRate' : 100 });
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var jinx = {videoId:'zWe4I6dXvms', loopstart:0};
        var yasuo = {videoId:'5fP58jVo4sU', loopstart:20};
        // $('#wrapper').tubular(yasuo);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure how to proceed, and i need to concentrate on the important details of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black is coming from the heimer.css style sheet (background: black):

```
body {  
  background: black
  url('/heimer.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 80% 40%;
}
```

Just change it to:

```
body {  
  background: url('/heimer.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 80% 40%;
}
```

Comment: but that only makes it white instead.. I want the image to stretch

Comment: i'm looking at the site, but it seems you figured out the stretching bit. glad you got it to work!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding fixed that helped. Appreciate it tho dude.